# Selectors to scrape lists between two elements with defined words

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

Trying to scrape parts of Tables of Contents (toc), ideally with SoupSieve:

```
<html>
<dl>
#many rows
<dd>4.2.1. Drivers</dd>
<dd>4.2.1.1. itemD1</dd>
<dd>4.2.1.2. itemD2</dd>
<dd>4.2.1.3. itemD3</dd>
<dd>4.2.2. Constraints</dd>
<dd>4.2.2.1. itemC1</dd>
#many more rows
</dl>
</html>
```

Note that the items I need are NOT children/descendants of 4.2.1. Drivers, only look like they are because of the numbering.

Now, the elements I need to scrape are those between the elements Drivers and Constraints. It's not always 3 of them - it may be 0 or 3 or 5, depends. Later on in my code I am using pandas to output these elements into individual cells in .csv.

I've tried things like this:

```
def get_drivers():
    data.append({
        'url': url,
        'type': 'driver',
        'list': [x.get_text(strip=True) for x in toc.select('dd:-soup-contains-own("Drivers") ~ dd')]
    })
```

... but this just gives me all the  elements from Drivers to the end of the document, often dozens of elements that I don't need.

Question: how can I get selectors to start selecting after Drivers and stop selecting at Constraints?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide an [mcve] in order to clearly understood your question as it's currently mixing things out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can absolutely do this with css selectors. Use `:-soup-contains` and `:not`, along with general sibling combinator (`~`) and type selector (`dd`) to filter out what comes after each (i.e. subtract  `Constraints` onwards from  `Drivers` onwards

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''<html>
<dl>
#many rows
<dd>4.2.1. Drivers</dd>
<dd>4.2.1.1. itemD1</dd>
<dd>4.2.1.2. itemD2</dd>
<dd>4.2.1.3. itemD3</dd>
<dd>4.2.2. Constraints</dd>
<dd>4.2.2.1. itemC1</dd>
#many more rows
</dl>
</html>'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
filtered = [i.text for i in soup.select(
    'dd:-soup-contains(" Drivers") ~ dd:not(dd:-soup-contains(" Constraints"), dd:-soup-contains(" Constraints") ~ dd)')]
```

I guess a loop might work as well though less preferable IMO:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''<html>
<dl>
#many rows
<dd>4.2.1. Drivers</dd>
<dd>4.2.1.1. itemD1</dd>
<dd>4.2.1.2. itemD2</dd>
<dd>4.2.1.3. itemD3</dd>
<dd>4.2.2. Constraints</dd>
<dd>4.2.2.1. itemC1</dd>
#many more rows
</dl>
<dl>
<dd>Error</dd>
</dl>
</html>'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
start = soup.select_one('dd:-soup-contains(" Drivers") + dd')
next_node = start

while True:
    if not next_node:
        break
    if 'Constraints' in next_node.text:
        break
    print(next_node.text)
    next_node = next_node.find_next('dd')
```

Comment: Thank you! I think this loop is likely to work, though I haven't tried yet. I tried the compound selector and that doesn't work - it misses out the node with Constraints in it, but then just carries on selecting noted till the document's end. Sure - I would prefer a compound selector that snugly fits into one set of brackets :). Perhaps it requires using nth-of-type?

Comment: If it doesn't work, I think your actual source html must be different. Is there an actual html to work with? If you the run the code above, as is, you should see the expected output.

Comment: Sure. https://www.marketresearch.com/Infogence-Marketing-Advisory-Services-v4010/Global-Active-Smart-Intelligent-Packaging-30323497/ In this example (the Table of Contents tab), the term Constraints should actually be swapped for Restraints.

Comment: I'm sorry it works! A typo on my side earlier. Plus it only works with i.get_text rather than i.text - perhaps due to my using html.parser rather than lxml, or because of the way I'm using it later in a dataframe(?). But, anyway, the code works beautifully. Thank you very much! Now, I'm off to understand exactly HOW it works...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors